# Pyomo and Gurobi: Does Pyomo support solver callbacks to Gurobi?

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I have started using Pyomo for modelling of MILPs and need to add problem specific cutting planes at certain MILP-feasible solutions. I know that it is possible to do that via callbacks in Gurobi's own gurobipy API. However, since I am using Pyomo atm I would like to stick to it if possible. I have seen that there exist persistent/direct solver IO options, however, I could not figure out how to make use of those options for my purposes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks and lazy constraints are currently supported by Pyomo for the Gurobi Persistent solver interface. Here is a small example from the documentation of that interface:

```py
from gurobipy import GRB
import pyomo.environ as pe
from pyomo.core.expr.taylor_series import taylor_series_expansion

m = pe.ConcreteModel()
m.x = pe.Var(bounds = (0, 4))
m.y = pe.Var(within = pe.Integers, bounds = (0, None))
m.obj = pe.Objective(expr = 2 * m.x + m.y)
m.cons = pe.ConstraintList()  # for the cutting planes


def _add_cut(xval):
    # a function to generate the cut
    m.x.value = xval
    return m.cons.add(m.y >= taylor_series_expansion((m.x - 2) ** 2))


_add_cut(0)  # start with 2 cuts at the bounds of x
_add_cut(4)  # this is an arbitrary choice

opt = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
opt.set_instance(m)
opt.set_gurobi_param('PreCrush', 1)
opt.set_gurobi_param('LazyConstraints', 1)


def my_callback(cb_m, cb_opt, cb_where):
    if cb_where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        cb_opt.cbGetSolution(vars = [m.x, m.y])
        if m.y.value < (m.x.value - 2) ** 2 - 1e-6:
            print('adding cut')
            cb_opt.cbLazy(_add_cut(m.x.value))


opt.set_callback(my_callback)
opt.solve()
assert abs(m.x.value - 1) <= 1e-6
assert abs(m.y.value - 1) <= 1e-6
```

```
Changed value of parameter PreCrush to 1
   Prev: 0  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 0
Changed value of parameter LazyConstraints to 1
   Prev: 0  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 0
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
adding cut
```

For further details on the methods available within this Pyomo callback interface, see the `GurobiPersistent` class.